# Can I get a solution using "timeout" when using Optimize.minimize()?

Tags: z3, z3py, optimathsat

I'm trying to minimize a variable, but z3 takes to long in order to give me a solution.

And I would like to know if it's possible to get a solution when timeout gets triggered.

If yes how can i do that?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by *"solution"* you mean the latest approximation of the optimal value, then you **may** be able to retrieve it, provided that the optimization algorithm being used finds any intermediate solution along the way. *(Some optimization algorithms --like, e.g., `maxres`-- don't find any intermediate solution).*

**Example:**

```py
import z3

o = z3.Optimize()
o.add(...very hard problem...)
cf = z3.Int('cf')
o.add(cf = ...)
obj = o.minimize(cf)
o.set(timeout=...)
res = o.check()
print(res)
print(obj.upper())
```

Even when `res = unknown` because of a timeout, the `objective` instance contains the latest approximation of the optimum value found by `z3` before the timeout.

Unfortunately, I am not sure whether it is also possible to retrieve the corresponding sub-optimal model with `o.model()` (or any other method).

---

For [**OptiMathSAT**](http://optimathsat.disi.unitn.it/), I show how to retrieve the latest approximation of the optimum value and the corresponding model in the unit-test [`timeout.py`](https://github.com/PatrickTrentin88/omt_python_examples/blob/master/unit-tests/timeout.py).

Comment: Thx for the help! But I'm getting minus infinite (-1*oo) Do you know why?

Comment: Im trying to minimize

Comment: Another question: Can I instead of using timeout to exit, can i use an if condition? If yes, how can i do that?

Comment: I guess it's the lower bound -- If minimeze gets lower than a certain limit exit from solver

Comment: @AndreOliveira In minimization the `lower` is updated upon *unsatisfiable binary-search steps*  and the `upper` is updated upon *satisfiable linear-/binary-search steps*, so you ought to check the value of `obj.upper()`. I didn't find anything in `z3`'s API to do the other thing you have asked about. It would be pretty trivial to do it with `OptiMathSAT`, using either the option `opt.abort_interval` or the option `opt.abort_tolerance`, or by writing a custom `msat_termination_test` callback function.